# How to auto select text of input filed inside bootstrap popup

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popup

Basically, I'm trying to achieve [this type of functionality](http://jsfiddle.net/learner73/gb96oh0q/) which is working in the normal time. But, [it's not working inside bootstrap popup](http://jsfiddle.net/learner73/4exrL66w/) (click "Share" button to see the popup). How to make it working inside bootstrap popup?

Code:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputShare" placeholder="" value="http://apps.companyName/wba" />

$('#inputShare').focus();
$('#inputShare').select();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well i came across exact same issue few days ago. you should set focus and select the text when modal is shown.

this is how i resolved it:

```
 $(".modal").on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
     $(this).find("#inputShare").focus().select();
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put your js inside the event of the bootstrap's popup.

```
$('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
//your code here
})
```